# Better HTML-annotation practice for an element that is a member of multiple classes

Tags: html, css

This isn't *quite* the same question as many others that it might resemble.

Consider a table full of sortable columns. The ascending/descending sort order that the visitor wants is kept in a `<span>` in the column's `<th>`. JavaScript code refers to that `<span>` when the user calls for a sort; and the code changes the contents of the `<span>` as the user toggles the sort order.

Considering both the code and the HTML, is it "better" (cleaner, JS-friendlier, more concise, nicer-looking) practice to annotate the `<span>` part of the `<th>` this way:

```
<span class="sortorder"><span class="ascending">content</span></span>
```

or this way:

```
<span class="sortorder ascending">content</span>
```

The first way makes it easier for code to track down the column's sort order. The second way rids the HTML of a lot of cruft. As it seems to me.

Thanks!

Comment: How about HTML5 `data` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you're trying to do is to add a key=value pair to the element that says "the sortorder of this is 'ascending'". For this I'd use [HTML5 data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

```
<span data-sort-order="ascending">…</span>
```

They should be backwards-compatible and jQuery should be able to find / read them on any browser they support using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).